# Nginx Wordpress Configuration, PHP file in theme directory is not passed to FastCGI

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi, subdirectory

I am new to NGINX configs so bear with me. Below is my configuration which works fine for the whole site:

```
server {
listen ...;
server_name  funkyoslo.no;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/funkyoslo.webbr.org/html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/funkyoslo.webbr.org/html/;
}
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/funkyoslo.webbr.org/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

However, I am trying to load the file /wp-content/themes/funkyoslo/load-songs.php and it's giving me a 500 internal server error. I've checked the error logs and evidently the file isn't passed to FastCGI at all.

I tried adding the following block to no avail:

```
location ~ .*/wp-content/themes/funkyoslo/.*\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/funkyoslo.webbr.org/html/wp-content/themes/funkyoslo/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look I don't know what's wrong with your config but try this and hopefully it should work, this is the minimal config.

**Notes**:

- Removed the index to the server block level, check [link](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Multiple_Index_Directives) to know why
- Removed root to server block level, check [link](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block) to know why
- Removed all extra config from the php block level, by trials I realised that I only need those two I've written.
- Added `http://` to `fastcgi_pass`, I don't know if it's really required but I got used to writting it this way.

**Edit**: Ok apparently I don't need the `http://`, I just checked.

-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  funkyoslo.no;
    root /usr/share/nginx/funkyoslo.webbr.org/html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following errors:
[emerg] 8088#0: invalid host in upstream "http://127.0.0.1:$
[error] 8109#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle wh$

Comment: Adding: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` seemed to help for the root directory, but the problem with /wp-content/themes/funkyoslo/load-songs.php persists.

Comment: Nevermind, it works now! Apparently there was an error in my PHP-file (due to different php.ini on my pc and the VPS) which was revealed in the PHP-FPM error logs. I was unable to spot it since the AJAX load was giving me a 500 Internal Server error.  

I don't think there was anything wrong with my initial config, though you have provided me with a much better setup now, thanks! :)